# Adding attribute in jQuery ( do not overwrite )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I add an attribute into specific HTML tags in jQuery?( I dont want to overwrite )

I have it in HTML:

```
<td style="width: 30%">Hello</td>
```

style="width:30%" is important.

Now I'm using a function () and adding attr:

```
$(cell_above_old).attr('style', 'vertical-align : middle;text-align:center;');
```

But the style is overwritten:

```
<td style="vertical-align : middle;text-align:center;">
```

What I want is to add the line to the existing style.

```
<td style="width:30%;vertical-align : middle;text-align:center;">
```

There is some function to do this?, such as:

```
$().attr('addStyle','styles');
```

Comment: Personally I'd say to just create some css classes and then use addClass removeClass, because that doesn't overwrite other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of thing is best done with classes. Add/remove classes with that styling as needed (via [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/), and/or [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)).

But if you want to do it with an inline style, use [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/), not [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$(cell_above_old).css({
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    textAlign: 'center'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(cell_above_old).attr('style', 'vertical-align : middle;text-align:center;');
```

That is setting the entire attribute value.  Change the css instead

```
$(cell_above_old).css({
    'verticalAlign': 'middle',
    'textAlign': 'center'
});
```

This will change just that css property in the style, leaving the rest alone.